# Why is createSelector erroring in this simple example?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, reselect

```
import { createSelector } from 'redux-starter-kit'

const getTodos = (state: any) => state.todos;

const blah = createSelector(getTodos, (todos: any) => {
    return todos
})
```

I have created the simplest recreation of the issue I am having using the library `reselect`. This version of reselect is the one that is ported for convenience from `redux-starter-kit`. In my Typescript code I am getting a syntax highlighting error inside `createSelector` for the `getTodos` param, which says the following:

[image]

Could anyone help with why this is happening? Is there a problem with the types file that is being used?

Answer (score 0):

After trying to figure this out for hours, I tried importing the library directly instead of using `redux-starter-kit`. Turns out the typings used there were completely different, and I found this in the [docs](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-starter-kit/blob/master/docs/api/createSelector.md):

> Note: Prior to v0.7, RSK re-exported createSelector from selectorator, which allowed using string keypaths as input selectors. This was removed, as it ultimately did not provide enough benefits, and the string keypaths made static typing for selectors difficult.

I had been using `redux-starter-kit 0.6.2`. Problem solved.